# I have written a code for creating a linked list. While printing the list items I am getting SIGSEV error. How do we fix it?

Tags: c++

I know I have done a silly mistake and to not make it again in the future I want to know why this error is showing up in the following code. I have already read on the internet that it is caused when our program is trying to access memory block which is not yet created but I cannot find where it is occurring in my program.

Thank You, Guys.

```
struct node
{
  int value;
  struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node Node;

Node *createNewNode(int value)
{
  Node *result = new Node;
  result->value = value;
  result->next = NULL;
  return result;
}

Node *insertHeadNode(Node **head, Node *nodeToInsert)
{
  nodeToInsert->next = *head;
  *head = nodeToInsert;
  return nodeToInsert;
}

void print_list(Node *head)
{
  Node *temp = head;
  while (temp != NULL)
  {
    cout << temp->value << "->";
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
  int value, i;
  Node *head;
  Node *tmp;

  while (i < 5)
  {
    cout << "Enter the value of the linked list: ";
    cin >> value;
    tmp = createNewNode(value);
    insertHeadNode(&head, tmp);
    i++;
  }

  print_list(head);

  return 0;
}
```

One more thing. I have dynamically created a struct in the createNewNode function. So we do delete it at the end of our program, right?

Comment: `int value, i;` -- `i` is not initialized.

Comment: You can prevent  countless bugs just by always initializing your variables.

Comment: Where do you initialize `*head` in your program?  You're taking an uninitialized pointer and using it as if it has been initialized.

Comment: You set `nodeToInsert->next = *head;` in `insertHeadNode`, but `Node *head` is not initialized. As of that `nodeToInsert->next` holds an indetermined value for the pointer.

Comment: If we declare variables in C++, doesn't it initialize them with a default value?

Comment: @two43pm *If we declare variables in C++, doesn't it initialize them with a default value?* -- Local variables that are fundamental types (such as `int` and pointers), no.

Comment: Is there a reason insertHeadNode takes a pointer to a pointer instead of just taking the pointer for an argument? Similarly why have the leak-prone createNewNode method instead of a constructor for the `node` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple parts in your code that result in undefined behavior.

You never initialize `i` so doing `i < 5` isn't valid.

You never initialize `Node *head` so that one also holds an indeterminate value, that value is assigned to `nodeToInsert->next` in `insertHeadNode`.

So also `cout << temp->value << "->";` would be invalid, at the point when `temp = temp->next` has reaced the node for which you assinged that indeterminate to `next`.

Comment: Yeah, I corrected the bug. Changed the initialization code of **head** Node by doing 
`Node *head = NULL;`